# File tools in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

[image]What is the use of the download files tool under files tools in QGIS 3.4.3?
I'm trying to bring a csv file directly from the web into my processing modeler but even when the tool runs successfully there is no output

Is there any other way to bring attribute data in QGIS using processing modeler directly from the web

Comment: What "download files tool"? I can't see anything like that in my QGIS. Is it in a menu or a dialog box?

Comment: @Spacedman I have added the photo in the question

Comment: If the tool isn't working then maybe the URL is wrong - how can we tell? If I put https://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv in the URL field I get that downloaded to a temp file successfully.

Comment: I'm also able to download the file to a temp file but the file doesn't load automatically once the command is executed. Even when I try to run it as a batch process it doesn't show up (I have checked open the output after completion box)

Comment: How have you connected the output from this tool in your model? Can you share those details?

Comment: do you have the url for the csv file?

Comment: yes @Mapperz and thanks for providing a step by step guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **QGIS 3.6** this is available.

[image]

In this case downloading a Google Earth file from the City of Vancouver (Opendata)

(you do not need to save the file if just processing.)

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Download file' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/temp/boundary.kmz', 'URL' : 'https://data.vancouver.ca/download/kml/city_boundary.kmz' }

Execution completed in 3.06 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/temp/boundary.kmz'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Download file' finished
```

This works well when you chain a lot of url's together in the processing toolbox...

like

[image]
[image]

and then select your attribute you require

(in this case NAME='Vancouver')